# ACF Form Allow Script Tags for a Specific Field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a textarea in ACF for my footer scripts. The issue I am having is within acf_form, basically if I try to enter  tags, they are getting stripped when I save the settings.

For example, the following code:

```
<script>
console.log('foo'); 
</script>
```

Will become the following after saving:

```
console.log('foo');
```

Within WP-Admin, the  tags are not being stripped, this is only happening within acf_form on the frontend.

Is there a way to allow these types of tags on the frontend for a particular field?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately not @JeanR. - I tried a few things but I ended up just having this be editable in the backend only as apposed to the frontend ;/

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign unfiltered capability. This is not allowed by default. To allow script tag, use the following code

```
// alllow unfiltered capability
add_filter('acf/allow_unfiltered_html', 'kp_acf_allow_unfiltered_html_all_fields');
function kp_acf_allow_unfiltered_html_all_fields() {        
    return true;
}
```